# AGM Google maps set tilt

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I have implemented AGM in Angular 6 for my mapping imagery.

and everything is working, however in with the standard Google Maps SDK
I could set tilt=0 so that the map would not automatically tilt when zooming in.

I can not see a property in AGM to do this? am I just missing it?

Here is my AGM component call...

```
<agm-map 
        [latitude]="lat" 
        [longitude]="lng" 
        [mapTypeId]="mapType" 
        [mapTypeControl]="mapControls" 
        [zoomControl]="mapControls" 
        [streetViewControl]="mapControls" 
        >

      </agm-map>
```

** mapControls: boolean = false;

any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

In `.ts` file:

```
private _map: any;
changeTilt(map) { this._map = map; this._map.setTilt(0); }
```

and in view:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="options.zoom"
      [mapTypeId]="'hybrid'" (mapReady)="changeTilt($event)" > </agm-map>
```